# OR, AND with Where by using Zend\Db\Sql\Sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework2

I'm trying to change this normal SQL statment, where I use "where" with or, to a `Zend\Db\Sql\Sql` Object.

However I cant figure out how to write the "where" clause.

this is the code before:

```
 SELECT column 
 FROM Table
 WHERE value = num OR value2 = num
```

and this is how i'm trying to make it look like:

```
 $sql = new Sql($adapter);
 $select = $sql->select();
 $select->from(Table);
 $select->where(?);
```

Comment: What class are you using?

Comment: it is Zend\Db\Sql\Sql

Comment: `$sql->where(array('id = ?' => $id));` would work, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In simple case, only have AND. You can use

```
$select ->where(array('cloumn1'=>'A', 'column2'=>'B'));
```

In complex case:

```
$where = new \Zend\Db\Sql\Where();

$where
    ->nest()
    ->equalTo('table1.column2', 2)
    ->or
    ->equalTo('table1.column3', 3)
    ->unnest()
    ->and
    ->equalTo('table1.column1', 1);
$select->where($where)
```

Comment: Could you shift your answer? Moving the simple case solution on top and the extended version for complex statements to the bottom? For reference purposes? :)